# StreamingFileSink unable to rename an inprogress file

Tags: google-cloud-storage, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I occasionally keep running into an issue when StreamingFileSink attempts to rename an inprogress file. See exception below:

The FS is mounted on Google Cloud Storage buckets. It works fine most of the times and suddenly fails.

I have verified that the inprogress file exists. Any hints suggestions will be very helpful - Thanks !

```
2019-11-12 01:26:44.908 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-77] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph - Job kafka-ingestion-avro-enriched-structured-trace-event-staging (b2f5e85f57049e0841a88498fcda868d) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING.
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/data/rawdata/2019-11-11--19/.part-0-0.inprogress.a99cb596-8e96-4b88-ae60-e5b64875bb74 -> /var/data/rawdata/2019-11-11--19/part-0-0
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalRecoverableFsDataOutputStream$LocalCommitter.commitAfterRecovery(LocalRecoverableFsDataOutputStream.java:181) ~[flink-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.commitRecoveredPendingFiles(Bucket.java:137) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.<init>(Bucket.java:119) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.restore(Bucket.java:346) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.DefaultBucketFactoryImpl.restoreBucket(DefaultBucketFactoryImpl.java:64) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.handleRestoredBucketState(Buckets.java:177) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.initializeActiveBuckets(Buckets.java:165) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.initializeState(Buckets.java:149) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink.initializeState(StreamingFileSink.java:334) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:278) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:738) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:289) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:704) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same problem, I bet this has something to do with eventual consistency or file system simulation using object store. I used `gcs://` based paths instead and it seems to work fine now.